# Which, which book/one

Tags: grammar

Can you use *which* as a pronoun in this sentence?

> Which are you reading, the old book or the new one?

I mean is it necessary to use a noun or pronoun after *which* and say "which **book/one** are you reading?", or is it possible to use *which* alone as a pronoun in the question

> Which are you reading?

Comment: Grammatically, it's fine. As regards clarity, context may well license the interrogative pronoun choice (but one is reminded of Tommy Cooper's 'I've come to read your gas meter.... Once upon a time ...'). The determiner usage is more definitive, of course. [Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/which) gives the modern (more logical) classification, and examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *which* as the lone pronoun is fine, provided that some context has already been established; i.e. the person to whom you direct the question already knows you are not referring to a newspaper, web article, or magazine.  Aside from that consideration, it's a matter of style.